# Number of form values as posting to one variable and writing it into separate rows in database using PHP ?

Tags: php

I am working on a php project where I have a user and has to undertake a risk assessment - they have to give the hazard type and give it a value of severity and likelihood for all hazards.  I want to then record this in the database as separate rows.

The columns in database table looks like
**hazard_id, hazard_type, severity, likelihood**

The form fields would look like:
**hazard type** (*text field*), **severity** (*drop-down*) and **likelihood** (*drop-down*)

So I would have say 13 repeated lines of the above down the page - all with the same name?
or would you have **hazard_type1**, **hazard_type2** etc

Then I want to post the values to the database so that each hazard shows as different row in the database.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would `hazard type` be a text field on the form, surely that should be static readonly text.

Comment: We are suggesting possible hazards to help but they can edit them as they wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays you just have to name your input fields properly

```
name="hazard_type[1]"
```

will be visible as

```
$_POST['hazard_type'][1]
```

In your case I would use

```
name="data[1][hazard_type]"
name="data[1][severity]"
name="data[1][likelihood]"
name="data[2][hazard_type]"
name="data[2][severity]"
name="data[2][likelihood]"
etc
```

then in PHP you can use

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
foreach ($data as $element) {
  $hazard_type = $element['hazard_type'];
  $severity = $element['severity'];
  $likelihood = $element['likelihood'];
  /* Here save each element into db */ 
}
```

Comment: So would I have:       
 <select name="data[1][severity]" size="1">
                  <option>-- Choose --</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>  

Then in post: $severity = $_POST['severity'][1][2];

Comment: I have this then as the insert which is only inserting one line?

$query = "INSERT into hazards (assessment_id, hazard_type, severity, likelihood) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$hazard_type' , '$severity' , '$likelihood');";
  mysql_query($query);

Comment: @php_beginner
'Foreach' will loop through all results so your query will be repeated and will insert multiply values. Also escape user input with mysql_escape_string before putting it into MySQL query. There are new libs for db access: PDO and mysqli. The one which you are using is being depreciated

Comment: Sorry I haven't been in touch but only back working today - it only reads in the last entered row of values - any ideas?

Comment: @php_beginner try 
print_r($_POST)

Comment: Sorry one more question:                        Is there a way to amend the foreach loop to multiply severity * likelihood to give a risk calculation for each hazard_type?

Comment: $risk = $severity * $likelihood;
?

Comment: thank you - I have the risk writing to the database as you suggested above but is there a way that I can show this figure on screen before the form is SUBMITTED to the database - i.e. by the click of a calculate button to give the risk associated with each line.  I have some javascript but not sure how to reference the input names - I tried this but it never worked:  document.calc.risk1.value = document.calc.(data[1][severity]).value*document.calc.(data[1][likelihood]).value;

Comment: if you assign ID to input fields then
document.getElementById('data_1_severity').value;

Comment: I have this javascript function which works fine but I wanted to add to it - that if the value of the calculation was less than 5 the input field changed colour to green or more than 5 it change to blue 

    function validate_form ( )
{
    valid = true;
 
document.calc.risk1.value = document.getElementById('data_1_severity').value*document.getElementById('data_1_likelihood').value;
document.calc.risk2.value = document.getElementById('data_2_severity').value*document.getElementById('data_2_likelihood').value;
    return valid;
}

Comment: are you using any JS library like jQuery?